# Set custom parameter in Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 routes

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Plugin",
        url: "{pluginName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I would like to use Html.Action helper and set "pluginName" parameter of my second Route.

I am try to use next code

```
@Html.Action("Index","Person",new RouteValueDictionary { { "pluginName", "myPlugin" } });
```

and to get link like

```
http://mydomain/myplugin/Person/index
```

but I've getting

```
http://mydomain/Person/index?pluginName="myPlugin"
```

How can I get first link pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your more specific route first.  The routing engine evaluates routes in the order you register them.  So if you have a fairly generic route registered early on (which you do), the routing engine will use it and append other values as QueryString parameters (which your seeing).

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Plugin",
    url: "{pluginName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```